# JS Date returns wrong date when using timezones

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm in a GMT+1 with summer time (GMT+2), using MS Edge with Language set to English (United States). Creating a new Date from the same date but with different years returns different locale date strings.

```js
new Date("1979-09-10T22:00:00.000Z").toLocaleDateString()
// "9/10/1979"

new Date("1980-09-10T22:00:00.000Z").toLocaleDateString()
// "9/11/1980" -> correct day in my case
```

I'm guessing that the locale used has had a reform regarding timezones in these years. How can I check what the cause of this is?

Comment: Likely you'll find that in one year it was standard time so +1 and 23:00 on 10 Sep local, but the other year it was in DST so 00:00 on 11 Sep local. What IANA location is the system set to? Note that many places have changed their dates for observing DST from time to time, and whether they observe it at all. ECMAScript Date objects are required to observe historic changes.

Comment: PS You can check for historic timezone changes at [*timeanddate.com*](https://www.timeanddate.com). e.g. for [*Europe/Amsterdam*](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/netherlands/amsterdam).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [IANA data at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) to get canonical IANA representative locations that currently have offset +1 and DST of some kind that didn't return the expected strings for "1979-09-10T22:00:00.000Z" and "1980-09-10T22:00:00.000Z" returned a list of:

1. Loc: Africa/Casablanca Std: +01:00 DST: +00:00
2. Loc: Africa/Ceuta Std: +01:00 DST: +02:00
3. Loc: Africa/El_Aaiun Std: +01:00 DST: +00:00
4. Loc: Europe/Andorra Std: +01:00 DST: +02:00
5. Loc: Europe/Belgrade Std: +01:00 DST: +02:00
6. Loc: Europe/Dublin Std: +01:00 DST: +00:00
7. Loc: Europe/Gibraltar Std: +01:00 DST: +02:00
8. Loc: Europe/Zurich Std: +01:00 DST: +02:00

A quick check on [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/) to find which of the above observe DST of +2 now but didn't 1980 reduces the list to:

1. Africa/Casablanca
2. Africa/Ceuta
3. Europe/Andorra
4. Europe/Belgrade
5. Europe/Gibraltar
6. Europe/Zurich

All currently have a standard offset of +1 and DST of +2, but didn't observe DST in 1979 or 1980. So likely you're using one of those locations (or another location that links to one of the above as an alias or because it's deprecated).

Some locations represent numerous other locations, e.g. Europe/Zurich is also the canonical location for [Europe/Busingen](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/germany/busingen-am-hochrhein) and [Europe/Vaduz](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/liechtenstein/vaduz) and is also used for [23 other named places](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/?query=Europe%2FZurich).

DST is likely to continue to change in Europe in particular as the EU wants to stop observing DST entirely. From 2020, member countries had a choice whether to continue to observe it or not. Some will continue to observe it, some will go to their standard offset all year round and some will go to their DST offset all year round. Expect other parts of the world to start messing with offsets more frequently too.

There are also places like Ireland that observe their standard time in summer (+1) and wind their clocks back 1 hour in winter (+0), which is why Europe/Dublin appears to have DST of -1 hour over winter. :-)

Comment: Great answer. The timezone didn't have a DST at the date in question. Is there a way to figure out which timezone JS is using (by name, e.g. Europe/Vaduz)?

Comment: @Johannes—not reliably. *toLocaleString* with the *timeZoneName: 'long'* option may produce the civil name, but such names are not standardised and you may get different results in different implementations for the same place. Also note that civil timezones are defined by administrative boundaries, whereas IANA representative locations (e.g. Europe/Vaduz) really means "the historic timezone offsets and DST changes as for this particular location" and may apply to other locations, but don't have defined geographical boundaries (though I believe Google is attempting to do so empirically).